# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application Logging with Logback

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logback

EDIT: Added Image (The problem looks like log files are not written)

I am running an spring mvc (NOT springboot) WAR file on AWS Elastic Beanstalk on a 'Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.1.3' environment.

Everything is working as expected EXCEPT application logs that I write with slf4j/logback.

The following is my logback.xml configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="APPLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/java.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>/var/log/java_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 14 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the File size reaches 10MB -->
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%thread][%X{remoteHost}] %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <!-- <pattern>%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</pattern> -->
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.personal.service.layer.mongodb" level="INFO"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="APPLOG" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="APPLOG" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="spring.web" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="APPLOG" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="APPLOG" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

After searching google/stackoverflow, I have added an ebextensions folder with a config file to include my logs with the tail logs and bundle as follows:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/applogs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/log/*.log

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/applogs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/log/*.log
```

After some research online, I have tried some other combinations. For example, I have tried to set the log file in logback.xml as `/var/app/current/logs/applog.log` and in the conf files used `/var/log/current/logs/*.log`, instead of what is shown above, but they did not work either. So I feel like I am missing something about logging to AWS with Logback.

I am also open to (working) suggestions about logging with other something else (log4j, java logging, etc).

EDIT: Finally figured out the aws/eb mess, and was able to ssh to the environment. I do not see java.log created under the folder var/log (or any other folder to the matter).

Why would logback not be writing the logs? Is that logpath `/var/log/java.log` not usable?

[image]

Comment: Are the log files saved where you think they are? Can you ssh into the EB instance, and inspect the logs?

Comment: I am trying but not being able to. Just installed aws and eb on my windows computer, but still haven't figured out how to ssh to an existing environment. When I do eb init (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html) it does not list my existing application. I've added the API key, but still not working. Will keep digging for now.

Comment: `eb ssh` is usually sufficient, assuming you enabled ssh when you created your env.

Comment: Updated question with more details. Looks like the problem is with log writing than retrieving, any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working for me now, thanks to the accepted answer in [Logback with Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043117/logback-with-elastic-beanstalk), which I asked as well.

I want combine what I learned from both questions here because this question is about reading logs where as that question is about writing logs, and it would be nice to have complete answer in one place.

The following are the changes I made to the logback.xml and ebextensions config file as mentioned in the question:

(1) In logback.xml, update `<file>/var/log/java.log</file>` to `<file>/var/log/tomcat/java.log</file>`

(2) In the ebextensions config file, update `/var/log/*.log` to `/var/log/tomcat/*.log` (this is optional, it will work even if it is left as `/var/log/*.log`)

The reason why it was not working in `/var/log` folder is because of the permissions to the folder. When I ssh to the folder, I found that the permissions to that folder is limited to `root` user only.

[image]

However, when the app is running with Tomcat, it is running as the user `tomcat` which does not have permission to write to that folder. However, the user `tomcat` has permission to write to the `/var/log/tomcat` folder.

[image]

The another folder I found which the `tomcat` user has access to is the folder created for the app `/var/app`. So if the log file location is set inside that folder in logback.xml, it would work as well (it would also require updating the ebextensions config file to point to that location).

It took me a couple of days to finally figure this out, hope it will help others as well.

P.S. I took out the `ConsoleAppender` from my logback.xml, it was doing nothing.